# What is a database prefix in web applications?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am working with search engine optimization.

I have a problem with db, i.e.:

```
define('PHPDIG_DB_PREFIX','<dbprefix>');
```

I know the db name, host name, password. But in an open source they are mentiong that `PREFIX` line.

I'm just confused. What should I use for prefix?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand at all. The internal naming of tables has nothing to do with Search Engine Optimization.

Comment: @pekka my problem is i did not use prefix in mysql query. this is new for me i used table name only.try to understand my question.

Answer (score 7):

Usually this means a prefix for the table names in multi-tenant applications (those sharing one database) to avoid name conflicts.

Say, `Wordpress` tables will start with `wp_*`, `Mantis` ones with `mantis_` etc.

You didn't mention what exactly was your problem, so I cannot tell you which prefix should you use.

If your database is only used by one application, you can pick any prefix you want, just leave it empty, or, best, use the application name for it, like `PHPDIG_`.

If the database is used by other applications, you should pick a prefix which does not conflict with those used by the other applications.

If you are using an existing database installation, you should fill the prefix used by this installation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you are abit confusing :)
Having said that: Sometimes you have a db-prefix If you don't have that. leave it empty.