# DB_PREFIX and security against SQL injections and other attacks

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe a stupid question but just curious. Couldn't find anything on search.

So I know DB_PREFIX is used to differentiate between different tables in a db, which might come from a different "source" [as pointed out here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747545/what-is-a-database-prefix-in-web-applications)

Im using DB_PREFIX which is declared as a constant in config.php 
As I continue my learning journey with PHP this is the first time I'm working with DB_PREFIX (modifying someone elses script)

So I was just curious, consider the following simple statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT gameID from ". DB_PREFIX . "schedule WHERE weekNum = :weekNum AND homeID = :homeID";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $week);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':homeID', $teamName );
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $IDs = $stmnt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($IDs as $ID){
            $gameID = $ID['gameID'];
        }
        //echo $gameID;
        return $gameID;
    }
    else {
        die('Error getting game id: ');
    }
```

config.php

```
define('DB_PREFIX', 'bru_');
```

1. Does DB_PREFIX provide some "extra" layer of security?
2. Is it good practice using DB_PREFIX?

Comment: 1. Not really 2. It depends. The advantages are already listed in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a custom prefix in all application tables can serve two purposes:

- Sharing the same database with other apps. That's something that only makes sense with really cheap hosting services—and in 2017 that means a really low-cost service.
- Having a multi-tenant application (a single app that splits its data across several copies of the same table set). These kind of apps tend to be a maintenance nightmare.

It can't possibly add any extra security because it doesn't attempt to. It isn't a security feature at all. In fact, for the security standpoint it could be argued that it can actually increase risks. If you are sharing storage with some other arbitrary application it's very likely that you're also sharing the same MySQL user with the same read and write privileges on the complete database. In such case, the other app can easily wipe out your tables, either intentionally or by mistake.

About the good practice part... That's always fairly subjective. My personal opinion is that it provides a dubious benefit (sharing a database is like sharing bath water, it only makes sense if you live in a desert) and it makes writing SQL code more annoying. For instance, you can no longer copy and paste between your PHP code and your MySQL client and, if you use an IDE that recognises SQL inside PHP strings, you'll no longer get proper code intelligence.